# Confusion about matrix differentiation in a nonlinear matrix equation

Tags: matrix, matrix-equations

I am trying to solve a matrix equation in the following discrete form:
$$
\frac{K^{n+1}-K^n}{\Delta t} = [(K^{n+1} (V^{n})^T).^3 - K^{n+1} (V^{n})^T]V^n.
$$
where $K^{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}, V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, $V^T V = I$(identity matrix) and $.^3$ are elementwise operations.

I am attempting to solve using Newton iterate method, which means I need to differentiate the function F：
$$
F = K^{n+1}-K^n-\Delta t[(K^{n+1} (V^{n})^T).^3 - K^{n+1} (V^{n})^T]V^n.
$$
I differentiate F with respect to $K^{n+1}$ and get:
$$
\frac{\partial F}{ \partial K} = I_K - \Delta t [3(K^{n+1} (V^{n})^T).^2  (V^{n})^T - (V^{n})^T]V^n.
$$
In my understanding, if a matrix is differentiated with respect to itself, the result should be an identity matrix. However, since $K \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$ is not a square matrix, how should this be handled? How can I solve the matrix equation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The directional derivative of $A^3$ in direction $B$ is $A^2B+ABA+BA^2$, there is no further reduction as the matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: @LutzLehmann That was my first reaction, too, but then I noticed that those in OP's question are elementwise products, not matrix products.

Comment: Ok, if that is indeed a compact form to write the discretized version of a PDE, then the factor 3 is correct. But then also, as per the answer, the identity matrix is not correct.

Answer (score 5):

If a matrix is differentiated with respect to itself, the result should be a fourth order tensor. The easist way to see this is to work with components.

$$
\frac{ \partial K_{ij}}{\partial {K_{kl}}} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}
$$

$\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). Because differentiation survives only when $i=k$ and $j=k$.  If your matrix is symmetric, then

$$
\frac{ \partial K_{ij}}{\partial {K_{kl}}} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} + \delta_{il}\delta_{jk}
$$

Because, the differentiation also survives for $i=l$ and $j=k$.

Edit:

The correct answer for a symmetric matrix is

$$
\frac{ \partial K_{ij}}{\partial {K_{kl}}} = \frac{1}{2} (\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} + \delta_{il}\delta_{jk} )
$$

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4105048/derivative-of-symmetric-matrix-with-respect-to-its-elements)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If $K \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, then the tensor corresponding to $\partial K$ is of size $m \times n \times m \times n$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct, that's the standard ordering for $\frac{ \partial K_{ij}}{\partial {K_{kl}}}$

Comment: If you are just interested in the directional derivative in a direction $H$, though, i.e., $\frac{d}{dt} F(K+tH)$ that's an $m\times n$ matrix (which is a function of $H$).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm missing a factor of 1/2 in the symmetric case.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I would be grateful for a better explanation of the symmetric matrix derivative wrt itself, than the one I linked to.

Comment: @NNN I don't think I have a better one; my remark above is about the fourth-order tensor part, not about symmetry.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  Sorry - I wasn't clear. I don't quite get where the factor of $1/2$ comes from. It comes from averaging the matrix and its transpose. I guess I'm looking for a clearer explanation on how to take a "constrained derivative". The link I posted in the edited post gives an explanation for the $1/2$ but I'm looking for something better.

Comment: @NNN I feel like this should be a separate question, not something buried in a comment thread. This has little relevance to OP's question: their matrix is not symmetric, it's not even square.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\large\tt1}}
\def\D{{\cal D}}
\def\k{\otimes} \def\h{\odot}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}  \def\mt{\mapsto}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$First let's clean up some variable names by stripping off unnecessary decorations
$$\eqalign{
\LR{\Delta t,V^T,K^{n+1},K^n} \;\mt\; \LR{h,A,X,Y} \\
}$$
Let's also use standard notation for elementwise products and powers
$$\eqalign{
X^{\h 3} = X\h X\h X \\
}$$
And introduce the all-ones matrix $\o\in\R{m\times n}$
and identity matrix $I_m\in\R{m\times m}$

Rewrite the function and calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
F &= X - Y - hI_m\BR{\LR{XA}^{\h 3} - XA}A^T \\
dF &= dX - hI_m\BR{\LR{3\LR{XA}^{\h 2} - \o}\odot\bR{dX\,A}}A^T \\
}$$
To avoid introducing tensors, [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the equation
and calculate the Jacobian
$$\eqalign{
df &= \vc{dF} \\
  &= dx-h\LR{A\k I_m}\,\vc{\LR{3\LR{XA}^{\h 2}-\o}\odot\bR{dX\,A}} \\
  &= dx-h\LR{A\k I_m}\,\c{\Diag{\vc{3\LR{XA}^{\h 2}-\o}}}\,\vc{dX\,A} \\
  &= dx - h\LR{A\k I_m}\,\c{\D}\,\LR{A^T\k I_m}dx \\
J\doteq\grad fx
  &= I_{mr} - h\LR{A\k I_m}\,\c{\D}\,\LR{A^T\k I_m}
  \;\in\; \R{mr\times mr}
}$$
NB: The Jacobian is a symmetric matrix.

Newton's method requires calculating $J^{-1}\,$ at every step, which is a standard operation for a matrix, but what does that mean for a fourth-order tensor?

IOW, you could calculate an expression for $\large\grad FX,\,$
but what would you do with it?